# How can I apply Huffman coding correctly?

Tags: matlab

I applied the zigzag function after quantization to an image block, and I want to compute the Huffman coding of this block.  I understand that the input argument must be a vector, and that the histogram should be calculated.

I wrote the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
[M N]=size(yce);
fun1=zigzag(yce);
count1 = imhist(fun1);
p1 = count1/ numel(fun1);
[dict1,avglen1]=huffmandict(count1,p1); 
comp1= huffmanenco(fun1,dict1); 
Im1 = huffmandeco(comp1,dict1);
```

I get the following error with the `huffmandict` function:

```
Error in project at 65
[dict1,avglen1]=huffmandict(count1,p1); 
Source symbols repeat.
```

zigzag.m is a written function in a matlab file.it converts a matrix into a vector,thus eliminating long sequences of zeros.

Comment: I know what zig-zag ordering does.  It would be useful if you displayed what `fun1` looks like so I can try and reconstruct your error.

Comment: fun1 is a vector.<1x6400 double>

Comment: Type in `numel(unique(fun1))` and tell me what the result is.

Comment: i see 147 in the workspace

Comment: I will edit my post.

Comment: still gives an error:Error using ==> histc
Edge vector must be monotonically non-decreasing.

Comment: You're ten steps behind buddy.  I deleted that comment and modified my post.

Comment: still gives an error:>> bins = unique([0; unique(fun1)]);
??? Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Comment: Again, check my edited post.  You're still referring to the comment that I posted.  Please **refresh your browser** and see the edits.  This is my last comment to you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Huffman encoding function (`huffmandict`)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/huffmandict.html) in MATLAB requires that the symbols vector (first argument of the function) **must all be unique values**.  This symbols vector is a list of all possible symbols that are seen in your data that you want to encode / compress.  As such, it wouldn't make sense to have a list of all symbols to be encountered if there are duplicates.  This is much like a dictionary of words, where it wouldn't make sense to see the same word twice in this dictionary.  The second parameter of the function is the associated probabilities of occurrence for each symbol in your sequence.

With `huffmandict`, what you are doing is you are creating a dictionary for Huffman encoding that consists of all possible **unique** symbols to be encountered when encoding/decoding as well as their associated probabilities.  Therefore, by examining your code, you need to extract both the **bin locations** as well as the probabilities of occurrence when using [`imhist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html).  Essentially, you need to call the two element output version of `imhist`.  The second output of `imhist` gives you a list of all possible intensities / symbols that were encountered in the data, while the first element gives you the frequency of each these intensities / symbols in your data.  You then normalize the first output element by the total number of symbols / intensities in your data to get the probabilities (assuming equiprobable encounters of course).  Once this is complete, you use both of these as input into `huffmandict`.

In other words, you need to change only two lines of code, thus:

```
[M N]=size(yce);
fun1=zigzag(yce);
[count1,x] = imhist(fun1); %// Change
p1 = count1/ numel(fun1);
[dict1,avglen1]=huffmandict(x,p1); %// Change
comp1= huffmanenco(fun1,dict1); 
Im1 = huffmandeco(comp1,dict1);
```

---

## Edit

Knowing how `fun1` is structured now, do not use `imhist`.  `imhist` assumes that you are putting in image data, but it doesn't look like that's the case.  Instead, try using [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) instead to compute the frequency of occurrence.  As such, simply modify your code to this:

```
[M N]=size(yce);
fun1=zigzag(yce);
bins = unique(fun1); %// Change
count1 = histc(fun1, bins); %// Change
p1 = count1/ numel(fun1);
[dict1,avglen1]=huffmandict(bins,p1); %// Change
comp1= huffmanenco(fun1,dict1); 
Im1 = huffmandeco(comp1,dict1);
```

[`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) finds those unique values that are in your vector so that we can use these as bins to calculate our frequencies.  This also figures out the all possible symbols seen in the data.

Comment: it still gives an error:The Huffman dictionary provided does not have the codes for all the input signals.

Comment: @matlabuser Performing this on a normal image worked for me.  That means there's something wrong with your input or what `fun1` is.  This was the code I used for a normal image.  I used `cameraman.tif` from MATLAB's path: `im = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')); [counts,x] = imhist(im); counts = counts / numel(im); [dict1,avglen] = huffmandict(x,counts);`

Comment: @matlabuser - oh! You accepted my answer!  How did you fix it?

Comment: still didn't work..i am implementing a compression scheme and this step comes after quantization

Comment: @matlabuser - Display what `fun1` is.  Edit your post.  Also, I don't have the `zigzag` function.  Is this a new MATLAB function, or something you wrote yourself?